# ES6 Find max of multiple values combined using reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following method which finds the user with the highest credits

```
let highest = this.users.reduce((max, current) => {
    current.credits > max.credits ? current : max, {credits: 0}
});
```

> Now I'm wondering how I can see who has the highest (credits + shots)

### I tried the following without succes, I'm getting undefined

```
let bestSupporter = this.users.reduce((max, current) => {
    (current.credits + current.shots) > (max.credits + max.shots) ? current : max, {credits: 0}
});
```

The following also isn't working (adding the shot to the initial value

```
let bestSupporter = this.users.reduce((max, current) => {
    (current.credits + current.shots) > (max.credits + max.shots) ? current : max, {credits: 0, shots: 0}
});
```

Comment: what should happen if more than one user has the same highest value?

Comment: That's a good question. Haven't thought of that. I'd like to fix this first haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With curly brackets in an arrow function, you need a `return` statement.

Then, you could use a start value for checking the value

```
let highest = this.users.reduce((max, current) => {
    return current.credits > max.credits ? current : max, 
}, { credits: 0 });
```

Or omit the start value and use the objects directy.

```
let highest = this.users.reduce((a, b) => a.credits > b.credits ? a : b);
```

Comment: Aha the second answer is working with a.credits+a.shots > b.credits+b.shots

Answer (score 2):

**I assume your logic is OK.**

You're not returning the new Accumulator.

```
let bestSupporter = this.users.reduce((max, current) => {
    return (current.credits + current.shots) > (max.credits + max.shots) ? current : max, {credits: 0}
}, {/*Initialize a value for your accumulator*/}});
```

If you don't want a `return` within your arrow function, then remove the curly-braces

```
let bestSupporter = this.users.reduce((max, current) => 
    (current.credits + current.shots) > (max.credits + max.shots) ? current : max, {credits: 0}
, {/*Initialize a value for your accumulator*/}});
```

Comment: I didn't know the curly braces and return thing! Thank you.